# Is it possible to make WinSCP use my SSH config file?

Tags: windows, ssh, winscp

I use SSH-based tools on Windows, which use configuration files in `%HOME%\.ssh\`.

Is it possible to make WinSCP use that configuration file too, so  I only have to manage one configuration?

It's redundant to have to keep two configurations for the same servers.

Answer (score 0):

WinSCP can import these OpenSSH data:

- sites from [OpenSSH `config` file](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_import#openssh_config)
- host key cache from [`known_hosts` file](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_import#openssh_known_hosts)